# May a woman shave her legs on Chol hamoed?

Tags: women, hair, chol-hamoed

The Shulchan Aruch tell us that one may not shave on Chol Hamoed ([Orach Chaim 531:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&pgnum=6)). Does this prohibition apply to women as well? Is a woman allowed to shave her legs on chol hamoed?

Comment: Cf. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10707.

Answer (score 14):

For women?  Yes.  [See here for more details.](http://text.rcarabbis.org/may-women-get-their-hair-cut-on-chol-ha-moed-halakhic-and-meta-halakhic-considerations-by-aryeh-klapper/)

שולחן ערוך אורח חיים סימן תקמו סעיף ה

עושה אשה כל תכשיטיה במועד; כוחלת ופוקסת (פי’ מחלקת שערה לכאן ולכאן רש”י), ומעברת סרק על פניה, וטופלת עצמה בסיד וכיוצא בו; והוא שתוכל לסלקו במועד; ומעברת שער מבית השחי ומבית הערוה, בין ביד בין בכלי, ומעברת סכין על פדחתה

Shulchan Aruch says women can do "any form of grooming on Chol HaMoed: makeup; combing; waxing?; shaving underarms, shaving "down below" ..."

I don't explicitly see "leg shaving" on the list, but by context and the other examples, it's fine.